# My tailwind project working properly at local server but not on github pages

Tags: tailwind-css, github-pages

hello guys I have created a basic project using html tailwind css and JavaScript and build it using vite build but the project working properly in local server but if I deploy it on github pages the tailwind and javascript not working. I don't know what's going wrong please help

my github repo.: https://github.com/Keshav-Rajput-31/portfolio-build.git
my github pages url : keshav-rajput-31.github.io/portfolio-build/

I have checked all paths etc but I don't get any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `'/'` from the stylesheet href. So, change the stylesheet href from `"/assets/index-TEE_z46_.css"`

**to**

`"assets/index-TEE_z46_.css"`.

Comment: but still a image that I have used as a background in header not showing 

line of code :- bg-[url('assets/bg3-4_GdHd4J.jpg')]

Comment: @Keshavrajput let me have a look.

Comment: @Keshavrajput The 'bg-[url()]' method is not working somehow. You need to add this before class-   style="background-image: url(assets/bg3-4_GdHd4J.jpg);"

Comment: Ohk Akshay thank you.

Comment: @Keshavrajput see and do it like this-  https://github.com/Keshav-Rajput-31/portfolio-build/commit/fd21018dbd96f33da8845558cfbb2489daf873a6?diff=split&w=1